# How to maintain variable throughout the application in c#? Multiple users access same variable with different values?

Tags: c#-4.0

string static str="User1";

Above in str variable we are storing User1 values.but another user store User2 value in same variable .is it possible are not.

Answer (score 0):

Use Singleton class

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/

singleTon classes are C# classes which instences can be only 1 in the application runtime so all you need is to save the str as prop of your singleton class include the class in whichever place you want in application

P.s microsoft link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx